# FTP to /var/www CentOS

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

I'm configuring an Apache server under CentOS 6.3. I want to put my app in

```
/var/www/html/<myApp>
```

But that directory is owned by root. How can I properly configure the access so I can publish files to that directory from a FTP client?

Initially I wanted to put my files under /home/myApp/wwwroot but that gives error messages as it seems under CentOS you're supposed to put your files under /var/www/html

What would be the right way of configuring this?

Comment: /home/myApp/wwwroot is perfectly valid. What is the error?

Comment: Probably you have to configure SELinux in order to put your files in /home/myApp/wwwroot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is:

- Create the `/var/www/html/YOUR_SITE` directory, and own to your ftp
  user
- Make sure `/var/www/html/` have the 755 permission;
- Create one user(please, dont use the ftp system user already created) and give the "ftpshell" to him. The home
  directory shall be `/var/www/html/YOUR_SITE`;
- Configure your favorite ftp daemon(mine is vsftpd) to chroot by
  default to the home folder. Read the docs ;)

Done. When you connect through ftp, it will seems to be that you are at /, and your user will not navigate on the entire filesystem hierarchy.